# Oracle link Sql Server, how to drop table

Tags: sql-server, oracle

How to delete a table in oracle using linked sql server?

```
select 1 from openquery(oralink, 'drop table temp')
```

Or

```
Exec('drop table temp', oralink)
```

> Error permission or does not create table.

Comment: clearly issue in permission, are you able to run a simple select ? and can you check if you have permission on the table from the sql server or the user from oracle also does it have permission

Comment: yes, there is a connection and select is done

Comment: ok then check from oracle `user` you have permission to drop table,  can you from oracle create a dummy table then drop it. then from sql server can you do the same ?

Comment: yes, in oracle client I can create and drop table. I can not run through sql server

Comment: why you cnnt run it through sql server?

Comment: I do not know, gives an error of impossibility of access, permission

Comment: found a solution: execute(@script) at OracleServer